# Lectura de archivo de texto

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa para administrar una tienda, decidi que los datos de los productos se guardaran en un archivo .txt y que estos se puediese imprimir en pantalla y al mismo tiempo, cuando el usuario presione una tecla, cada tecla corresponda a un producto y después hacer la suma del total de todos los productos ingresados. El problema es que no encuentro la manera de almacenar solo los valores numéricos en variables diferentes ¿ alguna idea ?

He intentado que el programa lea línea por línea el texto y guarde los datos en dichas variables diferentes, solo que me suelta error diciendo que la variable tiene que ser forzosamente char, y si es char no puedo hacer ninguna operación

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std; 

fstream archivo;
void leerarchivo1(){
    archivo.open("DatosUsuario.txt",ios::in);
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        string linea;
        while(getline(archivo,linea))
        {
            cout<<"Bienvenid@"<<" "<<linea<<" "<<":D"<<endl<<endl;
        }
        archivo.close();    
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"algo ha salido mal o.O \n Esto pordia deberse a que el programa de configuracion no ha sido corrido aun";
    }
}

void leerarchivo2(){
    archivo.open("nomredeTiendita.txt",ios::in);
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        string linea;
        while(getline(archivo,linea))
        {
            cout<<"Operando desde"<<" "<<linea<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"> = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = >INVENTARIO< = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = <"<<endl;
        }
        archivo.close();    
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"algo ha salido mal o.O \n Esto pordia deberse a que el programa de configuracion no ha sido corrido aun";
    }
}

void leerarchivo3(){
    archivo.open("Inventario.txt",ios::in);
    cout<<"inventario\n";

    if(archivo.is_open()){
    char c;
    while(!archivo.eof()){
        c = archivo.get();
        cout<<c;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No se encontro ningun registro de inventarios\n Vuelva a el programa de configuracion, ingrese los productos e intentelo de nuevo... u-u";
    }
    archivo.close();

}

void leerarchivo4(){
    archivo.open("Inventario.txt",ios::in);
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        int nproducto;
        char producto[50];;
        int precio;
        int num1;
        num1 = nproducto;
        while( !archivo.eof() ){
            archivo>>nproducto>>producto>>precio;
            cout<<"= + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +>o<+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + =\n";
            cout<<"["<<"Numero del producto: "<<nproducto<<" "<<" ][ "<<"Nombre del producto: "<<producto<<" "<<" ][ "<<"Precio: "<<precio<<" "<<" ] "<<endl;
            cout<<"= + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +>v<+ + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + =\n\n";
        }
        archivo.close();


    }
}

void leerarchivo5(){
    archivo.open("Inventario.txt",ios::in);
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        while(!archivo.eof()) {
        int numero1;
        fscanf(archivo,"%d\32",&numero1); 
        cout<<numero1;
         }      
        }
        archivo.close();


    }

int main(){
    leerarchivo1();
    leerarchivo2();
    leerarchivo4();
    leerarchivo5();
    system ("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

El contenido de cada txt es este:

```
DatosUsuario

Nahomy


nomredeTiendita
EVE

Inventario
1 Jabon 15
2 Papel 25
3 Escudo-Cokiri 13
4 Galletas-chokis 12
5 Helado 14
```

Comment: en que lenguaje estas programando? porque c# o c++ no tienen ninguna relacion mas alla que quizas la notacion puede ser parecida

Answer (score 2):

> El problema es que no encuentro la manera de almacenar solo los valores numéricos en variables diferentes ¿ alguna idea ?

Basta con mirar la gran cantidad de sobrecargas del operador de extracción de [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) (heredados gracias a `ifstream`) para ver que hay luz al final del tunel. Por otro lado nota que no hay ninguna necesidad de tener `archivo` como variable global.

El problema de leer en un `char[]`  es que no existe una sobrecarga para dicho tipo y, en consecuencia, el compilador no sabe cómo realizar la operación que le pides. Sin embargo sí que existe la sobrecarga para `std::string`:

```
std::ifstream archivo;
archivo.open("Inventario");
if(archivo.is_open()){
  int id, precio;
  std::string producto;

  while( !archivo.eof() )
  {
    archivo >> id >> precio >> producto;
  }
}
```